# The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint when inserting values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to insert data into a table but keep getting the following error: The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK__etudiant__dateNa__3D5E1FD2". The conflict occurred in database "gestionAbsEtud", table "dbo.etudiant", column 'dateNaissance'.

```
create table etudiant(
    numInscription int primary key,
    nom char(20),
    prenom char(20),
    sexe char check(sexe in('M','F')),
    dateNaissance date check(datediff(year, datenaissance, getdate())  between 15 and 30 ),
    email varchar(20),
    adresse varchar(20),
    idFiliere varchar(10) foreign key references filier);
    go
```

and this is the value i want to add :

```
insert  into etudiant values
(1,'elbaraa','HAMMAN','m','20001126','contact@baraa.tk','DI1');
```

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here, what about the error don't you understand and we can try to elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List the columns explicitly:

```
insert into etudiant (numInscription, nom, prenom, sexe, dateNaissance, email, adresse)
    values (1, 'elbaraa', 'HAMMAN', 'm', '20001126', 'contact@baraa.tk', 'DI1');
```

In general, this is a best practice.